# Windows 7 / ATI CCC - Monitor limit?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, amd-catalyst

I have a Ati 4850 X2 and back in the days when Windows 7 was in beta, I had this running with 4 monitors (Crossfire off). Now I have come to set this up again, with a RTM version of Windows 7 and the latest ATI drivers and it seems I can only have two monitors on at one time. If I try and set the monitors up in Control Panel, it simply disables the non-primary monitor, and if I attempt to do it in CCC, I get the message "To extend the desktop, a desktop or display must be disabled."

Does anyone know why this is and/or how to fix it?

I've currently tried using the latest ATI drivers and the drivers (i think) I was using over a year ago when I had this setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question but this was a bit odd. I installed using drivers from a while ago (not sure how old they are, found the exe lying around on my HDD) and arranged the monitors in CCC, not in Control Panel. This seemed to work fine, but the latest drivers do not work. Hopefully this might help someone in the future!

Comment: Do you know if we can get a copy of those older drivers anywhere? And what version they would be?

I bought a new one and it came with newer drivers so it's not working. But the old drivers would probably work.

Comment: If you want me to send you them or upload them somewhere I can, I haven't been able to find a link for them though :(